# Which city is destroyed if there are 2+ to choose from?

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

The barbarians attack. The player with the smallest army controls 2 cities, neither of which is a metropolis. Can they choose which one gets destroyed, or is this chosen at random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the rules only state that the player loses one of thier cities but not how to determine which city.

However, the mobile app comes in handy. I created the same conditions as you explained, and this is how they designed the game to handle the situation.

[image]

So the player decides which of their cities get pillaged.